Calculating number of permutations of an ordered set, only selecting in sequential order
I want to calculate the total number of permutations of selecting 3 elements from the set [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H], where the permutations respect the sequential order of the original set, i.e. potential permutations could be (A,B,C), (A,C,G), or (C,F,H); but can not be (C,B,G), (H,A,C) or (D,G,A).
How would I go about calculating this?
If I select the first item from the set, I have n-1 possible options for the next item, or if I select the third item from the set, I have n-3 possible options for the next item. But I am not sure how to take this further.

Contrast the stated enumeration with the enumeration of all combinations of 3 elements from the set.

The final paragraph of the post clearly states an effort to solve the problem.  I'm voting to reopen.

There are $\binom 83=56$ ways to choose $3$ elements from a set of $8$ elements.  For each distinct choice of $3$ elements, there is exactly one way to permute those elements to respect the ordering of the original set.  Therefore, there are $56$ permutations that respect the original set's ordering.

This makes sense to me! Thank you!

@RossMillikan Yeesh.  I can't believe I made that mistake.  Thanks for the catch.

Consider the following process:

Take every permutation of 3 elements from the set.

Sort each of those permutations.

Group together all duplicate permutations.


Can you see how the number of groups will be equal to the number that you're looking for?
Then since each group is just a collection of selections of the same 3 elements, what we're actually counting is the number of ways to choose 3 elements from the set, regardless of order.
